# Компиляция kivy под windows 3-х файлов

Tags: python, kivy

Никак не могу разобраться с проблемой компиляции kivy проекта. У меня есть три файла: main.py, xl_utils.py, phone.kv. Мне нужно собрать их всех в один исполняемый файл exe. Всё бы ничего, да PyInstaller отказывается принимать файл .kv. Как можно решить это проблему?

Comment: `pyinstaller main.py -w`

Comment: Но ведь если компилировать не один файл, а все 3, то pyinstaller ругается на файл kv

Comment: а что именно пишет?

Comment: выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса в первой строчке kv файла.
File "D:\PythonProjects\managers\phone.kv", line 3
<Window>
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Компилирую этим: pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py xl_utils.py phone.kv

Comment: Исключите из команды phone.kv, потом просто положите его в одну папку с экзешником.

Comment: Теперь появляется ошибка "Unable to find any valuable window provider". Я попробовал собрать таким же образом приложение с одной только кнопкой, но ошибка та же